# Push notification expo/react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, notifications, expo

I can push notification to an android device but when I'm on iOS I don't receive them. I tried different configuration and still don't have my notification on my iphone.

Yes, I'm using a device/yes my notification on my device is on.

```
"dependencies": {
 "expo": "22.0.0",
 "native-base": "2.3.1",
 "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
 "react-native": "0.49.3",
}
```

pushNotification.js

```
const PUSH_ENDPOINT = 'http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/tokens';
export default async () => {
let previousToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pushtoken');    
if(previousToken){
    return;
}else{
  let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.REMOTE_NOTIFICATIONS);

  if(status !== 'granted'){
      return;
  }

  let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

  console.log('token ',token)
  await axios.post(PUSH_ENDPOINT, {token: {token} });
  AsyncStorage.setItem('pushtoken', token)
}
};
```

Index.js

```
import registerForNotification from "./helpers/pushNotification";
ComponentDidMount(){
registerForNotification();    
Expo.Notifications.addListener((notification) => {
  const {data: {text}, origin } = notification;
  console.log(notification);
  if (origin === 'received') {
    Alert.alert(
      'New Push Notification',
      text,
      [{ text: 'Ok'}]
    );
  }
});
}
```